# Jetty HTTP2 server push support

Tags: jetty, server-push, http2

for SPDY, we need to implement a PushStrategy and to register it to push resources.

What about HTTP2 support?

I like the idea of nginx which consists to read link header in the HTTP response: https://nghttp2.org/blog/2015/02/10/nghttp2-dot-org-enabled-http2-server-push/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jetty HTTP/2 comes with full support for HTTP/2 Push, in fact in different flavors. [Webtide's website](https://webtide.com) already has Jetty's HTTP/2 Push enabled.

There is a [PushCacheFilter](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/PushCacheFilter.java), which implements the same algorithm that was implemented in Jetty SPDY's PushStrategy, based on the `Referer` header.

There is a [PushSessionCacheFilter](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/master/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/PushSessionCacheFilter.java), which implements a more sophisticated approach using a builder to actually push resources.

Both for now use Jetty specific APIs, in an attempt to propose them as standard for the Servlet 4.0 specification, and have them tested in real world examples.

The good thing about this approach is that entirely automated, and it does not require the application support: works out of the box with any old/legacy webapps.

The Jetty team can certainly explore the possibility of using the `Link` header, but that seem to require support from the application (the application has to add the `Link` header with the right format), and a proxy layer that impacts performances.
This is tracked by https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=463457, any contribution there is welcome.

In order to implement your own strategy to push resources, you can write a simple Servlet Filter, and in there use the Jetty specific API (i.e. `Dispatcher.push(...)` or the `PushBuilder` APIs) to push your own resources, similarly to what the above referenced filters do.

Comment: Ok can you just confirm that even if those filters are really efficient, no resource is pushed the first time a request is sent? If the application has any mechanism helping to detect the referenced resources at build time, then even the first request will take advantage from push? Moreover, when I check the PushBuilder, it seems to be able to avoid a push operation with last-modified/Etag headers. However those headers are retrieved from the initial request. For instance if I filter an HTML page, then an associated JS file will be pushed regarding the HTML page request's headers. Is it right?

Comment: The current filters do create a cache on the first request, so they only push from the second request onwards.
Currently there is no mechanism to "prefill" the cache so that it will push on first request, but it is an interesting feature to add. Please submit a feature request at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Jetty.
The goal of looking at last modified / etag headers is to avoid to push if the browser hints that it has the resource already in its cache. If the main resource comes with them, the JS should not be pushed.
I suggest we move this to the Jetty mailing list.