# Java Http/2 server

Tags: java, http, http2

I am new to HTTP world, and I been reading an [article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2916548/java-web-development/http-2-for-java-developers.html) about the development of the HTTP protocol until the most recent update at the end of 2015 for [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2).

Until now when you wanted to create a simple HTTP server in java you could use:

```
 HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0)
```

Like it's described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3732328/1129332) from 2010.

I want to know how can one build an HTTP/2 server today using only Java SE API?

Comment: *I want to know how can one build an HTTP/2 server today using only Java SE API?* You would need to write one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java HTTP/2 Server Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399182/java-http-2-server-socket)

Comment: @Pshemo Question said **today**. :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You got me. Also I missed the fact that Java 9 provides only client not server... Comment removed.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous posted stated, you cannot do this with only the Java SE API.  You can however use Jetty (a  3rd party Java API).

https://webtide.com/introduction-to-http2-in-jetty/

Answer (score 0):

Jetty has support for HTTP/2:

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/

Enable HTTP/2:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/http2.html

Answer (score 0):

Basic HTTP2 server using Undertow Server API:
https://undertow.io/

```
  Undertow server = Undertow.builder().setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ENABLE_HTTP2, true)
                .addHttpListener(port, host).setHandler(exchange -> {
                    System.out.println("Port: " + port + ", Client address is: " + exchange.getConnection().getPeerAddress().toString());
                    exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
//                  exchange.getResponseSender().send("Undertow Hi");
    
                }).build();
        server.start();
```